# How to link 2 cell of excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I want to link 2 cell of a excel sheet so that depending on changes on 1st cell the second cell will change.
I am novice in excel sheet so if it is a stupid question please forgive me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to select the second cell, and press `=`.  This will begin the fomula creation process.  Now either type in the 1st cell reference (eg, `A1`) or click on the first cell and press enter.  This should make the second cell reference the value of the first cell.

To read up more on different options for referencing see - [This Article](http://www.expresscomputeronline.com/20021216/techspace1.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

**Just follow these Steps :**

If you want the contents of, say, C1 to mirror the contents of cell A1, you just need to set the formula in C1 to =A1. From this point forward, anything you type in A1 will show up in C1 as well.

**To Link Multiple Cells in Excel From Another Worksheet :**

**Step 1**

Click the worksheet tab at the bottom of the screen that contains a range of precedent cells to which you want to link. A range is a block or group of adjacent cells. For example, assume you want to link a range of blank cells in “Sheet1” to a range of precedent cells in “Sheet2.” Click the “Sheet2” tab.

**Step 2**

Determine the precedent range’s width in columns and height in rows. In this example, assume cells A1 through A4 on “Sheet2” contain a list of numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively, which will be your precedent cells. This precedent range is one column wide by four rows high.

**Step 3**

Click the worksheet tab at the bottom of the screen that contains the blank cells in which you will insert a link. In this example, click the “Sheet1” tab.

**Step 4**

Select the range of blank cells you want to link to the precedent cells. This range must be the same size as the precedent range, but can be in a different location on the worksheet. Click and hold the mouse button on the top left cell of the range, drag the mouse cursor to the bottom right cell in the range and release the mouse button to select the range. In this example, assume you want to link cells C1 through C4 to the precedent range. Click and hold on cell C1, drag the mouse to cell C4 and release the mouse to highlight the range.

**Step 5**

Type “=,” the worksheet name containing the precedent cells, “!,” the top left cell of the precedent range, “:” and the bottom right cell of the precedent range. Press “Ctrl,” “Shift” and “Enter” simultaneously to complete the array formula. Each dependent cell is now linked to the cell in the precedent range that’s in the same respective location within the range. In this example, type “=Sheet2!A1:A4” and press “Ctrl,” “Shift” and “Enter” simultaneously. Cells C1 through C4 on “Sheet1” now contain the array formula “{=Sheet2!A1:A4}” surrounded by curly brackets, and show the same data as the precedent cells in “Sheet2.”

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

I Found Solution Of You Question But In Stack Not Allow to Upload Video See the link below it show better explain

[How to link two (multiple) workbooks and cells in Excel...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-foPogO3QNE)

Comment: -1 Link only answers are bad form on SO.  At least add a summary of the link (with attribution)

Comment: @ Jignesh.Raj see this thread [on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/159408)

Comment: You can still edit your answer to improve it. (Or delete it now that there are other good answers)