# Catching value changes in mirrored cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have used Worksheet_Change a lot to capture cell changes, but this time I want to listen to a mirrored cell. Let's say Cell A1's value is "=B1", so that A1 always shows B1's value. What I want to do is to make a script fire whenever what's *shown* in A1 changes. I can't just listen to B1 because the user has to be able to change the cell A1 gets its input from any time, it doesn't have to be B1, could be another cell in another worksheet.

The problem with using Worksheet_Change is that A1's value doesn't change when the mirrored value changes. A1's value will always be "=B1" or the chosen cell.

Hope you can help

Comment: Maybe Cells("A1").Value works for you.

Comment: No, it does not, becuase the value is "=B1", and doesn't change when B1 is updated.

Comment: I just ran this through the debugger, and if I put =rc[1] in A1 (which is the same as =B1 ), and put 1 in cell B1,  the value of  x = Cells(1,1).Value is 1, so the same as B1 and not "=B1"

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. You are however nog looking for Worksheet_Change but for another event. Worksheet.Calculate could help you, as that is what happens when someone enters a value in B1, A1 is recalculated. For info on this event see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838823.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not looking for Worksheet_Change but for another event, as nothing changes here, it only recalculates. Therefore Worksheet.Calculate could help you. For info on this event see: [this article from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838823.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to do this is just go to sheet and in range B1 type "=A1" 
Your question is very similar to this one [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136540/how-to-link-2-cell-of-excel-sheet)

Comment: My question might have been unclear. The question you linked to is about how to set up circular dependency. The point is to listen to the cell A1 is mirroring. A1 has value "=B1", but it could be any other cell, and I as a programmer don't know which cell it will be. I must somehow monitor what A1 *shows*, insted of it's actual value.